# Kerberos Java Credentials Cache

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos

I am running following code to interact with the kerberos enabled hadoop cluster.

```
val t1 = new Thread() {
            override def run() {
                println("output of first thread")
                val conf = new Configuration
                conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos")
                conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://192.168.23.206:8020")
                UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf)
                UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("dummy@platalyticsrealm", "E:\\\\dummy.keytab");
                val fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
                val status = fs.listStatus(new Path("/"))

                println(UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser().getShortUserName())
            }
        }
val t2 = new Thread() {
            override def run() {
                println("Running Thread 2")
                val conf = new Configuration
                conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos")
                conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://192.168.23.206:8020")
                UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf)
                UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("test@platalyticsrealm", "E:\\\\test.keytab");
                val fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
                val status = fs.listStatus(new Path("/"))

                println(UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser().getShortUserName())

            }
        }
        t1.start
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        t2.start
```

This code produces following output.

test

test

It means the second thread over-write the credentials obtained by first thread. 
I have following questions
 1. Where credentials are stored in my windows environment. I searched under C:\Users\username but i did not find.
 2. How can i tackle this problem of over-writing credentials cache when multiple users try to access hadoop at a time.

Thanks

Comment: If you were **not** using the Hadoop API, I would suggest you to **RTFM** > for global Kerberos settings, cf. http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/basic/ccache_def.html and `KRB5CCNAME` env variable > for Java settings, cf. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/AcnOnly.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Java code clearly uses **static methods** to set the **default, implicit, global, JVM-wide** UGI. That's what people need 99% of the time.

**But** if you need to serve multiple sessions for multiple users, in client-server mode, then clearly that cannot work. Please read [that tutorial](http://bryanbende.com/development/2016/03/20/learning-kerberos-and-ugi) chosen at random on a Google search, under section *"Multiple UGIs"*. Then do some research by yourself.

If you want to dig into the dirty implementation details, you might peek into that [awe-inspiring grimoire](https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/ugi.html) by the guy who actually maintains the Hadoop security code base *(also the Spark code base and the ZK code base)* and is not too happy about that.

Comment: I have used loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI this method. But I am getting following exception

Exception in thread "Thread-1" Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]; Host Details : local host is: "my-pc/192.168.23.53"; destination host is: "example.com":8020;

Comment: Look at the GitBook *(link above under label "grimoire")* for section **_Low-level Secrets_** >> how to enable the debug mode; also browse sections **_Errors_** and **_Terrors_** for a compendium of error messages and workarounds to try.

Comment: Also, since you want to use multiple Kerberos credentials in the same app, with non-default UGIs, you must use **specific** methods. Cf. tutorial when it says *"This is done through the **doAs(** PrivilegedAction action **)** method on UGI."*